# Does files in Files app resyncing consume more battery?

Tags: ipad, icloud, data-synchronization, ipados, files.app

I am worried it might consume more battery because the files in Files app keep unsyncing and I need to sync them again almost each time I open them.

I noticed that whenever there's a cloud with an arrow pointing down icon at the top right of a file, I will need to resync it before opening it.

[image: iOS Files app unsynced file example]

I have searched on this forum and on the Internet but haven't found anything answering my question on resyncing. Some sources say that syncing use battery a lot but not resyncing and I am to guess that once a file is synced once, it consumes lots of battery, but when it's resynced... I don't know.

My question is: Since I noticed my battery goes down significantly fast (old iPad, 6th gen) and I want to make my battery last as long as possible, does resyncing consume more battery than not resyncing (disabling syncing in iCloud Settings)?

EDIT: "Get infos" about the file.
[image: get infos]

EDIT 2: "Get infos" about a recently opened file which, after quitting and going back again to app, got unsync'd.
[image]

Comment: The file was *created* just two minutes before it was last accessed.  If the file gets changed on the host, then synced with iCloud, it will need to be resync’d.

Comment: Alright then. Since it was a zip file, I only needed to open it once to get the elements inside.

Comment: @Allan , I am now editing to add info on a recently opened file which, after quitting and going back again to app, got unsync'd. (In "EDIT 2")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> … does resyncing consume more battery than not resyncing (disabling syncing in iCloud Settings

Every single action you take on a device, whether new or old, consumes battery; this includes re-syncing files.

When your device does anything from redrawing the screen, reacting to a gesture or button press, anything, it requires CPU cycles.  That requires energy and thusly, requires battery.

When your device communicates it will require additional energy because not only does the CPU need power to operate, but the wireless chip will need power to process the data into wireless signals and the antenna assembly will need power to transmit and receive radio signals.

So, yes, downloading a file will require power.

The question you should be asking (yourself) is *why* do you have to keep downloading the same file?  Is it because you are out of space on your device?  Is it being updated constantly?  Getting to the bottom of this will help you in not expending excess power repeating the same activity and thus conserving battery power.

Comment: Thank you. It isn't only the one samd file downloading each time I want to open it, it is all the files I want to open. I have just checked and I have about 10 GB left in my iPad storage. Is it enough?

Comment: 10GB is plenty.  If you have optimize storage enabled, it will automatically remove apps/files you don’t use after a period of time.  So, if you don’t use this much, this is why you keep downloading it.

Comment: Where is optimize storage? I would like to check if it's enabled.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201656

Comment: I have checked, it isn't enabled. I do things manually sometimes such as deleting videos that take place but nothing much more than that.

Comment: Did you mark the file as “make available off line in iCloud”?

Comment: I haven't done anything and it does not show anything in the details. I am adding images of details and more info about the file as an edit to my question.

Comment: Edited. I don't think "infos" will be useful but maybe "get infos"?

Answer (score 1):

> Does files in Files app resyncing consume more battery?

**No**.

Presence of the cloud with downward arrow icon is an indication that the Files app has done a minimal sync  instead of a full sync. Meaning, the app knows that the file contents have changed but has not "downloaded" the changes themselves. The actual changes will only be downloaded when you tap on the icon to open/access the file.

If you are concerned about rapidly depleting battery, you may try turning on Low Power mode (can be found under Battery settings) and turn off Background App Refresh (can be found under General settings).

Comment: Alright, then, sorry if this is a second question but: How to automatically do a full sync instead of a minimal sync?